# Eventmachine 1.2.7 build fails with Ruby 2.5.1 on Amazon Linux AMI - "rhel fedora"

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos, eventmachine, ruby-2.5

Facing an issue while installing eventmachine gem on Amazon linux ami, works fine on ruby-2.3.6, breaks with ruby-2.5.1
Steps:
`gem install eventmachine` 

Note: `gcc version 7.2.1 20170915 (Red Hat 7.2.1-2) (GCC)`
Error logs:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing eventmachine:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
current directory: /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/ext
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180724- 
3006-y7es83.rb extconf.rb
checking for -lcrypto... yes
checking for -lssl... yes
checking for openssl/ssl.h... yes

checking for CLOCK_MONOTONIC in time.h... yes
CXXFLAGS=$(cxxflags)

creating Makefile
current directory: /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby 2.5.1/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/ext
make "DESTDIR=" clean
current directory: /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby- 
2.5.1/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/ext
make "DESTDIR="

compiling binder.cpp
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wmisleading-indentation’
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wimplicit-fallthrough=0’
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wduplicated-cond’
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wrestrict’

make: *** [binder.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/eventmachine-1.2.7/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the root cause of this is a mismatch in gcc and g++ versions on AWS, after an AWS kernel update. The solution is to run:

```
sudo yum remove gcc48-c++
sudo yum install gcc72-c++
```

see https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/issues/446

Comment: @shivam_v Takes time to leave comment, but doesn't upvote or accept the answer... 

Comment: apologies on that,but i did upvote you :)
Just that i have a reputation lower that 15, hence my upvotes are not publicly visible. You can help me to help you by upvoting my question i presume?